# Footer CSS Positioning

Tags: css

I have looked everywhere and I can't seem to find an answer to this - Obviously I am doing something wrong. Here is my footer css:

```
#footer { 
   position: fixed; 
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
   padding-top : 10px;
   background-image:url(../images/bottom_bg.jpg);
   background-repeat:repeat;
   text-align:center;
   border-top: 5px solid #000;
   font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size:12px;
   font-weight:bold;
   color:#FFCC66;
}
```

[www.bevwebdev.com/examples.php](http://www.bevwebdev.com/examples.php)

- what the heck am I doing wrong?? I've tried z-index, setting height only works for tables, position: absolute just sticks it on the middle of my shorter pages - what a headache!!!

Comment: Can you clarify what you need help with? Footer seems find to me - btw, your link is missing the .com

Comment: what about the footer don't you want?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you scroll down, the footer covers up the bottom part of the main container. The solution is to add a bottom margin to the `container` div.

```
#container {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

This puts 100px of blank-ness below the div so, when at the very bottom of the page, all of the text still shows.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want the footer to be below everything else, you should be using `position: relative`

If you always want the footer to be fixed to the bottom of the browser, you should be using `position: fixed`

If you always want the footer a certain distance from the another element or the top of the page, you should be using `position: absolute`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the bottom of the page to not be hidden under the footer add this CSS:

```
body {
    padding-bottom:100px;  
}
```

Or some number that works for you. This will push the body content up a bit so you can see it.